# input date month by name

Tags: javascript, date, input

Hello  I have this imput Date, with small changes:
- days available from tomorrow
- default day tomorrow
- and date format dd/mm/yyyy

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var day = ("0" + (now.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
  $('.dateD').val(today).attr("min", today);
});
```

But I need the month as a name not a number, January, February, etc...

so the date should be: 04/February/2017

here the example:
http://jsbin.com/rovuliyere/edit?html,js,output

thank you!

Comment: you can use jquery-dateFormat https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: I would normally recommend using libraries such as those already recommended, or Moment.js. However, if what you're doing is really small maybe it's not worth the overhead. Maybe this will help: `var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
months[now.getMonth() -1]`

Comment: "*so the date should be: 04/February/2017*" but according to your format it should be 2017-February-04.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Internationalization API](http://generatedcontent.org/post/59403168016/esintlapi) for that. This snippet only work on modern browsers. See [browser compability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```
var locale = "en-us",
month = now.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/bifagurege/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Though options for *toLocaleString* are only supported in recent browsers, e.g. IE 11, Safari 10, see [*MDN browser compatibility matrix*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Comment: Yes, That's true. But does it make any difference in my code?

Comment: Only that where support is missing the result will be unexpected (e.g. "05/02/2017, 2:10:32 am") and vary between browsers.

Comment: Yes I completly agree with you. Even I don't think it's a good idea but as someone already gave the better solution with an array , so I thought I can share it to him.

Answer (score 0):

you can try datepicker for formatting:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I know datepicker, but the idea is not to use extra libraries!

Answer (score 0):

> so the date should be: 04/February/2017

It's impossible to set(change) a custom format of `<input type="date" />`. It requires a full-date format equal to: *yyyy-mm-dd*
To render current Date in the format *dd/Month/yy* use the following short solution with [Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) :

```js
var now = new Date(),
  day = ("0" + (now.getDate())).slice(-2),
  // the first argument 'en-us' is a locale(you can adjust it)
  today = day + '/' 
          + now.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: "long" }) 
          + "/" + now.getFullYear();
  
$('.dateD').val(today).attr("min", today);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="dateD" type="text" readonly='true'/>
```

Comment: The first argument to *toLocaleString* is a language, "en-us" is a dialect. If omitted, the default language of the browser is used, which might suit better (and is a primary reason for the existence of *toLocaleString*).